# Create a function to insert new node on it`s correct position into a sorted singly linked list of dates

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I have a sorted singly linked list and I have to add a new node in correct position.

Here are my structs:

```
typedef struct date
{
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
} date;

typedef struct node
{
    date d;
    node* next;
} node;
```

And here is the function I made:

```
node* addNode(date pn, node* head)
{
    node* pnew = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    pnew->p = pn;
    pnew->next = NULL;
    
    for (node* i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next)
    {
        if (i->d.yy > pnew->d.yy)
        {
            if (i->d.mm != pnew->d.mm || i->d.dd != pnew->d.dd)
                continue;
            else
            {
                pnew->next = i->next;
                i->next = pnew;
                   break;
            }
        }
        else if (i->d.yy == pnew->d.yy && i->d.mm > pnew->d.mm)
        {
            if (i->d.dd != pnew->d.dd)
                continue;
            else
            {
                pnew->next = i->next;
                i->next = pnew;
                   break;
            }
        }
        else if (i->d.yy == pnew->d.yy && i->d.mm == pnew->d.mm && i->d.dd > pnew->d.dd)
        {
            pnew->next = i->next;
            i->next = pnew;
               break;
        }
        else if (i->d.yy == pnew->d.yy && i->d.mm == pnew->d.mm && i->d.dd == pnew->d.dd)
        {
            pnew->next = i->next;
            i->next = pnew;
              break;
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}
```

Actually I cheched if this piece of code works `pnew->next = i->next; i->next = pnew;`
And it works good, so the problem is connected with `if` statements. But I cannot find a mistake.

Comment: `for (i = head; i != NULL; i = i->next)` <<-- `i` is undefined.

Comment: After inserting the new node, you still continue the loop. You should stop looping.

Comment: Make a function to compare two nodes. Based on its return value, the loop can either advance in the linked list, or insert the new node and terminate.

Comment: Make a comparison function that accepts two `date *` and that returns `0` if dates are equal, and -1 or 1 depending on which is later than the other. In other words, separate the comparison logic and insertion logic.

Comment: Also consider using a `time_t` for the date. You can use `struct tm` to easily enter year, month and day. Then use `mtkime` to convert that to `time_t`. It leads to easier comparison. You can also opt to do this in a comparison function like @wildplasser and I described.

Comment: BTW: you are not handling the case wher head==NULL (empty list); and you are not handling the case where the new node should be inserted *before* head. Both cases can exist in the real world.